# Can we store encrypted secrets (securely) in environment variables?

Tags: security, encryption, environment-variables, encryption-symmetric

I've been reading about the many various ways to store secrets securely at machine-level and a lot of sources mention how secrets can be stored in environment variables, but warn that they're not encrypted. My question is, why can't we store an encrypted secret in the environment variable?

For example, we can use DPAPI to encrypt the secret and store that ciphertext in the environment variable, then the web service (that's running on that server) grabs the ciphertext from the environment variable and uses DPAPI to decrypt it in the code. What is stopping us from doing that in a production environment?

Is it possible, just not secure? If not secure, what makes it not secure?

Comment: If you encrypt the data you store in environment variables, it should be ok. What you should avoid is storing sensitive data as clear-text. Note that environment variables are easily readable by any process that run with the same account or same machine depending on the scope, so this is a place looked by malicious users.

Comment: Is there a better place to store them on the machine-level then, like the registry or ...? And agreed, the secret would definitely not be plain-text, thank you.

Comment: As long as this is encrypted, you can store it wherever you want. I would use the Credential Manager for a desktop application, or a configuration file for a service application. If possible I would use a Vault.